# How does running a package from ~ work?

Tags: terminal

I need to understand how does running a package from ~ work? When I `ls` my home directory the package that I am running it does not appear there.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How are you running it from `~`? I'd not expect the binary to actually be in your home directory (unless you're running it as `~/binary-name`), but rather a subdirectory.

Comment: Could be they think all commands should be in the current directory instead of path variable.

Comment: What is a package in this context?

Comment: I downloaded bsdgames and whenever I am in ~, if I type any game such as 'robots' it will run automatically, although the program is not in ~. I want to understand why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Welcome new BASH command line user!

Perhaps, the easiest answer to your question is that, on Unix type systems, the installed programs are located in a few common directories.  These directories are generally set as the default search PATH for executable files.

The ~ symbol is a shortcut way of writing out /home/user/

So, when you start a BASH terminal, you typically start in ~

If you want to see the search PATH, you can type the command:

```
env
```

And look for something that resembles:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

So, when you installed bsdgames, the program 'robots' was placed in one of those directories.  And you can find out WHICH directory by using the command:

```
which robots
```

On my system, I get this:

```
/usr/games/robots
```

Showing me that the program 'robots' is located on the search PATH, and therefore I can execute the program by simply typing it on the command line.

If you are interested in learning the GNU/Linux command line, there are numerous tutorials available on line.  It's difficult to know where to begin sometimes.

Hopefully this was helpful for you.